# TabLayout tab text color state list

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tablayout

I want my `TabLayout` tabs have three different text colors depending on tab state:

1. default - red
2. disabled - yellow
3. selected - green

I'm adding my TabLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tlBetTypes"
                style="@style/BetTabLayoutStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/single"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/multi"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/system"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

then `BetTabLayoutStyle`:

```
<style name="BetTabLayoutStyle">
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/BetTabTexStyle</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/background_tab_bet_type</item>
</style>
```

then `BetTabTexStyle`:

```
<style name="BetTabTexStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_12</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_test</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_medium</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

then `tab_test.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red"/>
    <item android:color="@color/yellow" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/green" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

But it's not working.

I also tried to create a `ColorStateList` from code and set and set is using `setTabTextColors`.

Could you please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps to solve this:

1. set `ColorStateList` *from code* because `TabLayout` resets text appearance in constructor if you inflate it in xml.

   ```
   private void setupTabsStyle() {
   int[][] states = new int[][]{
           new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected},
           new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},
           new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}
   };

   @ColorRes int[] colorRes = new int[]{
           R.color.orange_1,
           R.color.grey_16,
           R.color.grey
   };

   @ColorInt int[] colors = new int[colorRes.length];

   for (int i = 0; i < colorRes.length; i++) {
       colors[i] = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), colorRes[i]);
   }

   ColorStateList colorList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
   mTabLayout.setTabTextColors(colorList);
   }
   ```
2. Disable `TextView` inside the tab, not only the tab itself. In particular we need to disable/enable only the `TextView` inside the `TabView` to achieve text appearance effect, but I disable the `ImageView` as well.

   ```
   private void enableTab(int tabIndex, boolean doEnable) {
       LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0));
       LinearLayout tabView = (LinearLayout) tabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
       tabView.setEnabled(doEnable);
       for (int i = 0; i < tabView.getChildCount(); i++) {
           View childAt = tabView.getChildAt(i);
           childAt.setEnabled(doEnable);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried this?

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/defaultColor"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/whenTabSelectedColor"/>
```

Comment: yes, this won't work in my case. I need three states (disabled state)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<style name="BetTabLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
     <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">0dp</item>
     <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/BetTabTexStyle</item>
     <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/background_tab_bet_type</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, but still not working. Just wondering why this should work